# How can present a viewController with a different navigation in Xamarin for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xib

A navigation is already present in the application, but with a specific ViewController, i need to create a separate navigation. Is it possibile?? Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible create new navigation and set it as a rootview coontroller

Comment: How can i create it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the separate navigation in `AppDelegate` and set it as RootViewController of Window by trigger button click event or anything else.

#### AppDelegate

```
UINavigationController originNav;
UINavigationController newNav;

public void changeNavigation(){
    newNav = new UINavigationController(new UIViewController2());
    Window.RootViewController = newNav;
}

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    originNav = new UINavigationController(new UIViewController1());

    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    Window.RootViewController = originNav;
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
}
```

#### The ViewController inside originNav

```
//wherever
private void buttonClick()
{
    AppDelegate app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    app.changeNavigation();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answare. Just a question. What do you think about UIViewController1 and UIViewController2? Many thanks

Comment: They are just the initial viewcontroller in navigation , you can create them by `UIViewController vc1 = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null).InstantiateViewController("UIViewController1");` if they are contained inside storyboard.